# Passing arry to function matlab

Tags: arrays, matlab, function

I have the following code:

```
function [arrR, arrI]=funcmain()
....
for k=1:stage
  size=Len/(2^(k-1));
  for j=1:(2^(k-1))        
    arrR((j-1)*(size)+1:j*size)=func(arrR((j-1)*(size)+1:j*size),arrR((j-1)*(size)+1:j*size));
    arrI((j-1)*(size)+1:j*size)=func(arrI((j-1)*(size)+1:j*size),arrI((j-1)*(size)+1:j*size));
  end;        
end;
...
end;
```

and function func looks like this:

```
function [arrR,arrI]=func(arrR,arrI)
    Len=length(arrR);
    for i=1:(Len/(2))
        arrR(i)=arrR(i)+arrR(i+Len/(2));        
        arrR(Len/(2)+i)=arrR(i)-arrR(i+Len/(2));
        arrI(i)=arrI(i)+arrI(i+Len/2);        
        arrI(Len/(2)+i)=arrI(i)-arrI(i+Len/(2));    
    end;    
end
```

I am getting an error:

> Too many input argument.

To make it clear what the function does, I have for example an array, `arrR(1:16)` then I may want to pass `arrR(1:4)`, `arrR(5:8)` or any section of `arrR` to the `func` function and the function does what ever it should and return and plug it back to the right position of the original array, `arrR(1:16)`. So, if I had pass `arrR(1:4)` the corresponding result from `func` should be plugged in (`1:4` of `arrR(1:16)`).

And too bad mathworks is down today. :( what happened?

Thanks!

Comment: Can you copy the exact error message including where it occurs? As it is, the way you have called `func` from `funcmain` looks fine, so I doubt that is where the error is. Another things, you should avoid using `size` as a variable name as it is a Matlab function name. This could be causing you some problems too.

Comment: Thanks David for the reply. Here is the whole error message: Warning: File: func.m Line: 31 Column: 22
Function with duplicate name "func" cannot be called. 
Error using func. 
Too many input arguments.

Error in func(line 19)
           arrR((j-1)*(size)+1:j*size)=butterfly(arrR((j-1)*(size)+1:j*size),arrR((j-1)*(size)+1:j*size));                                                                       I changed the 'size' keyword, no change. I think it is possible to use it as a variable name.

Comment: Line 31-function [arrR,arrI]=func(arrR,arrI)     and                       Line 19-arrR((j-1)*(size1)+1:j*size1)=butterfly(arrR((j-1)*(size1)+1:j*size1),arrR((j-1)*(size1)+1:j*size1));

Comment: It's possible to use `size` as a variable name, but it's not good practice. I think the problem is in the name of `func`. Do you have any other functions in other `m`-files called `func`? Try renaming it.

Comment: I agree with the naming. There was func.svm file in the directory, I deleted it now but I still have the error message at line 19, "Too many arguments".

Comment: I can't give any more help without a small working example that reproduces the error. http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve